# Symfony Form builder: how to organise/group fields into HTML sections from the controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like in the form builder controller to say this field belongs to this group then in the view/theme organize all of group1 into div1, group2 into div2, etc..

I tried something like this (creating sub forms) but that is not working; I am not able to display the group

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('group1', FormType::class, array('inherit_data' => true))
        ->add('brand', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'brand',
            'invalid_message' => 'Enter a brand',
    ))
);
```

twig

```
{{ form_row(form.group1) }}
```

Comment: The error looks like it's comming from Twig. => Show us the template.

Comment: Your formType is OK. how do you think the error is associated with this lines of code?

Comment: humm that is the very first time I am trying to do this and did not realise the error could be coming from twig.. I think I am beginning to understand that I need to display `{{ form_row(form.group1) }}` ? tried, but it does not display the field, just the group name

Comment: but if I write `{{ form_row(form.group1.brand) }}` it works. How do I display the entire group with one line ?

Comment: ok got it, I will update the question since the error was irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is looking; my error was that I forgot to loop through

```
{% for row in form.group1 %}
     {{ form_row(row) }}
{% endfor %}
```